# How to define a shared build variable?

Tags: android, gradle, configuration, build.gradle

I'm trying to set up custom variable for each build type.

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildTypes {
    each {
        buildConfigField "string", "SHARED_URL", "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "string", "PRIVATE_URL", "https://debugoverflow.com/"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "string", "PRIVATE_URL", "https://releaseoverflow.com/"

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And I want to have an access to the `SHARED_URL` in my code by `final String sharedUrl = BuildConfig.SHARED_URL;` both in the debug and in the release build. So, how can I achieve this goal?

P.S. I'm understand that I can just copy variable `SHARED_URL` in the both builds, but I don't want to boilerplating.

Comment: "My build.gradle file looks like this" -- is `each` an actual build type? Or are you pretending that it is one, where you mean that you want that `buildConfigField` to be available across all build types? Also, you seem to have `.` instead of `,` in each of your three `buildConfigField` lines.

Comment: The `each` build is not the actual build type, it's as an indication that these variable is common to both builds. Thx, typos were fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your common `buildConfigField` in `defaultConfig`:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "string", "SHARED_URL", "https://stackoverflow.com/"
  }

  buildTypes {
      debug {
        buildConfigField "string", "PRIVATE_URL", "https://debugoverflow.com/"
      }
      release {
        buildConfigField "string", "PRIVATE_URL", "https://releaseoverflow.com/"

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
}
```

`SHARED_URL` will now be available for all build variants.